# Disable client-side validation in MVC 4 submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net mvc4 app, I get this error "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" for example when creating a new item "cond".
cond is a table in the database with two fields "id_regle" and "cond_txt".
The cond_txt fields will have conditions with the following form "left_side+op+right_side"; op= <, >, == ....
I tried different suggestions that I found, but non of them worked for me to disable this validation.

This is the view "create":

```
@model MvcApplication3.cond
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
 <h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>cond</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cond_txt)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cond_txt)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cond_txt)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id_regle, "regle")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("id_regle", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_regle)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="cancel" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.id_regle = new SelectList(db.regle, "id", "action");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Default2/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(cond cond)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.cond.AddObject(cond);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.id_regle = new SelectList(db.regle, "id", "action", cond.id_regle);
        return View(cond);
    }
```

I've tried adding validateRequest="false" in the web.config, but that didn't work for me
Any suggestions plz

Comment: possible duplivate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: where to put validateRequest="false"  ?? in mvc4 asp.net

Comment: I tried in <pages validateRequest="false"> in web.config but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me, I added [ValidateInput(false)] in the controller
 [reference](https://jwwishart.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/asp-net-mvc-pages-validaterequestfalse-doesnt-work/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below to disable the client side validation while control rendering.

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
```

or try this

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```